# System interactive pop gesture broken in UINavigationController when providing a custom animation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a custom subclass of `UINavigationController` that sets itself as the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, and conditionally returns a custom animator. I want to be able to toggle between the custom animator and the system animation using a boolean flag. My code looks something like this:

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var useCustomAnimation = false
    private let customAnimator = CustomAnimator()

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation,
                              from fromVC: UIViewController,
                              to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        if useCustomAnimation {
            return CustomAnimator()
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

However, when `useCustomAnimation` is `false`, the interactive back gesture managed by the system no longer works. Everything else related to the system animation still works.

I've tried setting the delegate of the interactive pop gesture to my custom navigation controller and returned true/false from some methods with varying levels of success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems this is a bug in UIKit. I've created a small project that reproduces the error and submitted it to Apple. Essentially the interactive pop gesture is broken whenever the `animationController` delegate method is implemented by the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. As a workaround, I've created two delegate proxies, one that implements the method, and one that does not:

```
class NavigationControllerDelegateProxy: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    weak var delegateProxy: UINavigationControllerDelegate?

    init(delegateProxy: UINavigationControllerDelegate) {
        self.delegateProxy = delegateProxy
    }

    /*
    ... Other Delegate Methods
    */
}

class CustomAnimationNavigationControllerDelegateProxy: NavigationControllerDelegateProxy {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                              animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation,
                              from fromVC: UIViewController,
                              to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return delegateProxy?.navigationController?(navigationController,
                                                    animationControllerFor: operation,
                                                    from: fromVC,
                                                    to: toVC)
    }
}
```

I simply alternate between these classes acting as the actual `UINavigationControllerDelegate` depending on the state of `useCustomAnimation`.